# More paths in psr-4

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm learning namespaces and psr-4 autoloading.
In my application I can load only the classes of the first object under psr-4 in composer.json.

I will explain better, this is my situation:

Folder Structure:

```
app
- core
-- Foo
--- Foo.php
src
- Bar
-- Bar.php
```

in composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": 
    {
        "psr-4":
        {
            "core\\"  : "app/core/",
            "myapp\\" : "src/"
        }      
    }
}
```

Only classes under app/core are loaded. If I use `\core\Foo\Foo` works like a charm, but if I use `\myapp\Bar\Bar` doesn't work. Of course I updated the autoload with `composer dump-autoload -o` and respected the Case Sensitive letters.

Where is my mistake? thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Does Bar.php have a class with the proper name and namespace? Check the generated autoload psr4 file in vendor/composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your current namespace in each of those files? According to your folder structure and setting in `composer.json`, these are the values you should have:

`Bar\Bar.php` should have

```
<?php

namespace myapp\Bar;

class Bar {}
```

while

`Foo\Foo.php` should have

```
<?php

namespace core\Foo;

class Foo {}
```

You should then be able to access them with `new myapp\Bar\Bar` and `new core\Foo\Foo`.

It's important that your filename and class name is the same.